# Enabling Pause feature on HBOT 3D 1.1

Tags: marlin, firmware, hbot-3d-1.1

At work, I have an HBOT 3D 1.1 printer and I need to be able to pause my prints. I've tried all the usual G-code commands (`M0`, `M1`, `M25`, `M226`, `M600`) but they don't work.

At home I have an Ender 3 and while I don't know much about modifying firmware, with help from a video guide I've managed to enable the advanced pause feature which solved exactly that problem.

Could anyone advise me what steps to take to enable pausing mid-print on HBOT 3D 1.1?

Comment: Do you have the (English) manual? This is a fairly old printer (2013?) which runs an old version of probably Marlin firmware, but could be topped of by OEM specific sources, the display e.g. is quite different as are the menu items if you look into the [Polish manual](https://manuall.pl/hbot-3d-1-1-drukarka-3d/#pf12). The question is if there is a way to pause the print at all, it might well be that it is not implemented.

Comment: Unfortunately I only have access to polish manual and I've failed to find anything useful in there. There is no section about updating firmware. I've looked into a configuration file on my SD card, but there's nothing interesting there either.